# Copy a Workbook to a new workbook via a separate workbook

Tags: excel, vba

Maybe my title could be tweaked a bit for someone else attempting to do but I have a number of workbooks that I want to duplicate but I want to do it from a separate workbook.
I have a number of workbooks listed in Col "B" of a sheet named "File List". What I'd like to do is open each one, create a new workbook and copy all of the sheets from the original one to the new one. I'm getting a "Type Mismatch" error in the code (noted below) & I can't figure out why?

```
Public OrigFN As String
Public NewFN As String
Public TempWB As Workbook
Sub Duplicate_Workbooks()
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Dim wb1 As Workbook, wb2 As Workbook
    Dim sht As Worksheet
    Sheets("File List").Activate
    Dim LRow As Long
    LRow = Range("B65536").End(xlUp).Row
    Dim x As Long
    For x = 2 To 2   ' step thru Col "B" on the "File List" sheet to get the names of the workbooks to duplicate
        OrigFN = Range("B" & x)
        On Error Resume Next
        Kill "C:\Test\Temp.xlsx" 'get rid of the Temp.xlsx workbook in the event that it exists
        On Error GoTo 0
        Set TempWB = Workbooks.Add
        With TempWB
            .SaveAs Filename:="C:\Test\Temp.xlsx"
        End With
        ' we now have a newly created workbook named "Temp.xlsm"
        Set wb1 = ActiveWorkbook
        Workbooks.Open Filename:="C:\Test\" & OrigFN     ' this is the workbook to copy "From"
        Set wb2 = ActiveWorkbook
        MsgBox "From: " & wb2.Name & vbCrLf & "To: " & wb1.Name
        ' above Msgbox indicates that the wb's are named correctly
        For Each sht In wb2.Sheets  'HERE IS WHERE I GET A TYPE MISMATCH ERROR
            sht.Copy after:=wb1.Sheets(wb1.Sheets.Count)
        Next sht
        ' my intention at this point will be to delete the OrigWB & rename "Temp.xlsx" to the OrigWB name
    Next x
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: First off, you will need to qualify your ranges so they do not assume `ActiveSheet`. Also, looks like you can delete the lines for `LRow` since you never use it.

Comment: You have declared `sht` as a worksheet yet you're looping through the sheets collection. Try `For Each sht In wb2.Worksheets` instead. Or if you want to include charts, declare `sht` as an object.

Comment: @VBasic2008 many of the workbooks I'm copying do contain charts so the "declare as object" worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

Considering the title of your question, wouldn't the method FileSystemObject.CopyFile do what you need in a much easier way?

Regarding your code, as you declared sht as Worksheet and you are looping through Sheet objects, you may be getting a type mismatch if your workbook contains a chart sheet.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).